# imgs are responsive in chrome developer tools but are not when deployed to mobile phone

Tags: html, css

Hey everyone I have been having trouble getting my imgs to be responsive on mobile phone when i deploy it. I heard that chrome developer tools are inaccurate for mobile testing, I have tried to add the meta tag for viewport, also I have tried to use Resolution test, to adjust it but the images are not responding, the 320px is inaccurate and the 414px is also inaccurate but 768px and 1024px are responding correctly. I have been on it for 2 weeks, any help would be appreciated!!

//html

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* font: normal 75% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; */
  }
  canvas {
    display: block;
    /* vertical-align: bottom; */
  }
  /* ---- tsparticles container ---- */
  #tsparticles {
    position: absolute;
    /* position: fixed; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0d47a1;
    background-image: url("");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    /* background-position: 50% 50%; */
    z-index: -1;
  }
  
  .github {
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 12px 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  
  .github a:hover,
  .github a:link,
  .github a:visited,
  .github a:active {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .github img {
    height: 30px;
  }
  
  .github #gh-project {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }
  

.bg-img {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}

#bgCanvas {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    offset-position: center;
    position: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}

/* span.navbar-toggler-icon {
    margin-right: 1em;
} */

button.navbar-toggler {
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.navbar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    /* flex-direction: row; */
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    
}

li.nav-item {
    /* font-size: 15px; */
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 1em;
}



a.navbar-brand {
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
    
}


h2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 5em;
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin-left: .5em;
}

h4 {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 1.1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;

}

section.paragraph-section {
    /* margin-top: 20em; */
    margin-top: 12em;
    margin-bottom: -90%;
}


span#intro {
    /* padding-top: 40%; */
    margin-top: 40%;
    /* margin-left: 3%; */
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    /* margin-left: 40%; */
    animation: appear 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* margin-left: 50%; */
    /* margin-left: 30px; */
   
    
}

@keyframes appear {
    from {
        left: -100px;
      
    }
    to {
        left: 154px;

    }
}

@-moz-keyframes appear {
    from {
        left: -100px;
    }
    to {
        left: 154px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes appear {
    from {
        left: -100px;
    }
    to {
        left: 154px;
    }

}

@-o-keyframes appear {
    from {
        left: -100px;
    }
    to {
        left: 154px;
    }
}

.name {
    color: white;
    /* margin-left: 38%; */
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 55%;
    margin-left: 38%;
    
}

@keyframes appear2 {
    from {
        left: -100px
    }
    To {
        left: 122px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes appear2 {
    from {
        left: -100px;
    }
    to {
        left: 122px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes appear2 {
    from {
        left: -100px;
    }
    to {
        left: 122px
    }
}

@-o-keyframes appear2 {
    from {
        left: -100px;
    }
    to {
        left: 122px;
    }
}

/* .introParagraph {
    margin-top: 10%;
    
} */

/* projects page css */
.paragraph-title {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    /* padding: 1em; */
}

.paragraph {
    /* margin-bottom: 8em; */
    color: white;
    margin-left: 2em;
    display: flex;
    /* flex-direction: row; */
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Amatic SC';
    font-size: 12px;
    /* padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px; */
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 2em;

}

.btn {
    background-color: lightsteelblue;
    /* margin-left: 32%; */
    /* margin-left: 30%; */
    margin-bottom: 8em;
    animation: bounce 2s;
}

@keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        transform:translateY(-100%);
        opacity: 0;

    }
    5% {
        transform:translateY(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    15% {
        transform:translateY(0);
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
    30% {
        transform:translateY(50%);
    }
    40% {
        transform:translateY(0%);
        padding-bottom: 6px;
    }
    50% {
        transform:translateY(-30%);
    }
    /* break */
    /* 70% {
        transform:translateY(0%);
        padding-bottom: 7px;
    }
    80% {
        transform:translateY(-15%);
    }
    90% {
        transform:translateY(0%);
        padding-bottom: 8px;
    }
    95% {
        transform:translateY(-7%);
    }
    97% {
        transform:translateY(0%);
        padding-bottom: 9px;
    }
    99% {
        transform:translateY(-3%);
    }
    100% {
        transform:translateY(0);
        padding-bottom: 9px;
        opacity: 1;
    } */
}

.intro-set {
    font-size: 2em;
}


button {
    margin-left: 25%;
    /* background-color: initial; */
    /* background-color: white; */
    border: 2px solid black;
    animation: button 2s;
    /* padding: 10px; */
    border-radius: 5%;
    background-color: lightsteelblue;

}

@keyframes button {
    0% {
        transform:translateY(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    15% {
        transform:translateY(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}


.introParagraph {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 60%;
    /* text-shadow: #FC0 1px 0 10px; */
    /* text-shadow: #28a7 1px 0 10px; */
    text-shadow: #28a745 1px 0 10px;
}

/* .project {
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 20px;
    
} */

.nav-item:hover {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 0;
    /* transition-delay: 2s; */
}

/* .nav-item {
    transition-delay: .1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
   
} */

/* projects page imgs */
img.first-img,
.second-img,
.third-img,
.fourth-img,
.fifth-img,
.sixth-img,
.seventh-img,
.eigth-img {
/* object-fit: contain; */
width: 200px;
/* margin-left: 4em; */
margin-left: 4em;
}

button.bTop {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
    margin-left: 36%;
}

/* #divButton {
    margin-bottom: 20%;
    margin-left: 13em;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
} */

form {
    margin-left: 23px;
}


/* MEDIAQUERY 414 */
@media screen and (min-width: 414px) {

    span#intro {
        margin-left: 11.2%;
    }

    .name {
        margin-left: 41%;
    }

    img.first-img,
    .second-img,
    .third-img,
    .fourth-img,
    .fifth-img,
    .sixth-img,
    .seventh-img,
    .eigth-img {
    /* object-fit: contain; */
    width: 200px;
    /* margin-left: 4em; */
    margin-left: 7em;
    }

    .btn {
        margin-left: 31%;
    }

    button.bTop {
        margin-left: 40%;
    }

    #divButton {
        margin-left: 29%;
    }
}

/* MEDIAQUERY 768 */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

.flex {
        display:flex;
        margin-left: 7%;
        margin-right: 5%;
    }

    /* project class 768px */
    .first-project.project {
        margin-left: 1em;
    }

    .eigth-project.project {
        margin-left: 3em;
    }


    img.first-img {
        margin-left: 2.5em;
    }

    img.second-img.img {
        margin-left: 26%;
        height: 235px;
    }

    img.third-img.img {
        height: 229px;
        object-fit: cover;
        margin-left: 18%;
    }

    img.fourth-img.img {
        margin-left: 4.5em;
    }
    
    img.fifth-img.img {
        margin-left: 4em;
    }

    img.sixth-img.img {
        margin-left: 22%;
    }
    img.seventh-img.img {
        margin-left: 3em;
    }

    img.eigth-img.img {
        margin-left: 4em;
    }

    .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav {
        margin: 46%;
    }

    #tsparticles {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }


    span#intro {
        margin-left: 24%;
        font-size: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -25%;
    }

    .name {
        margin-top: 30%;
        font-size: 25px;
        margin-left: 43%;
    }

    .introParagraph {
        margin-top: 30%;
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    /* h4 768px */
    h4 {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    /* projects paragraphs 768*/
    p.first-paragraph {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 2em;
    }

    p.third-paragraph {
        margin-left: 2px;
    }
    p.fourth-paragraph {
        margin-left: 1em;
    }
    p.fifth-paragraph {
        margin-left: 4px;
    }
    p.sixth-paragraph {
        margin-left: 2%;
    }
    p.seventh-paragraph {
        margin-left: 2em;
    }
    p.eigth-paragraph {
        margin-left: 1em;
    }


    /* projects btn styles 768*/
    .first-btn {
        margin-left: 25%;
        margin-top: 1.2em;
    }
    
    .second-btn {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .third-btn {
        margin-left: 22%;
    }
    .fourth-btn {
        margin-left: 25%;
    }
    .fifth-btn {
        margin-left: 23%;
    }
    
    .sixth-btn {
        margin-left: 5.8em;
    }

    .seventh-btn {
        margin-left: 5em;
    }
    .eigth-btn {
        margin-left: 5em;
    }


    h2 {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    /* flex box for project 3 and 4 768px */
    h4 {
        margin-left: 1em;
    }

    .third-h4 {
        margin-left: -4%;
    }

    .fourth-h4 {
        margin-left: -3%;
    }

    .eight-h4 {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    #divButton {
        margin-left: 39%;
    }

    button#bTop {
        margin-left: 45%;
    }
}


@media(min-width: 1024px) {
    /* .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav {
        margin: 35%;
        
    } */
    li.nav-item {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-left: 1em;
    }
    span#intro {
        margin-top: 25%;
        margin-left: 31%;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    .name {
        margin-top: 18%;
        margin-left: 44.5%;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    .introParagraph {
        margin-top: 25%;
        font-size: 35px;
    }

    button {
        margin-left: 42%;
        height: 3em;
        padding: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    /* container flex 1024px */
    .flex {
        margin-left: 4%;
        margin-right: 7%;
    }

    /* project class */
    .project {
        margin: 0px;
    }

    h2 {
        margin-right: 1.5em;
    }

    .fourth-project.project {
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

    /* h4 styles */
    h4.third-h4 {
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
    h4.fourth-h4 {
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
    h4.fifth-h4 {
        margin-right: 10%;
    }
    h4.sixth-h4 {
        margin-right: 12%;
    }
    h4.seventh-h4 {
        margin-right: 10%;
    }
    h4.eigth-h4 {
        margin-right: 10%;
    }

    /* projects paragraphs 1024px*/
    .paragraph {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    p.second-paragraph {
        margin-left: 2em;
    }
    /* p.third-paragraph {
        margin-bottom: 2.2em;
    } */
    p.fifth-paragraph {
        margin-left: 2%;
    }
    p.seventh-paragraph {
        margin-left: 2%;
    }
    p.eigth-paragraph {
        margin-right: 15%;
    }

    /* project imgs 1024px */
    img.first-img.img {
        margin-left: 25%;
    }
    img.second-img.img {
        margin-left: 34%;
    }
    img.third-img.img {
        margin-left: 23%;
    }
    img.fourth-img.img {
        margin-left: 30%;
    }
    img.fifth-img.img {
        margin-left: 24%;
    }
    img.sixth-img.img {
        margin-left: 26%;
    }
    img.seventh-img.img {
        margin-left: 6.5em;
    }
    img.eigth-img.img {
        margin-left: 24%;
    }

    /* project btn 1024px */
    .first-btn {
        margin-left: 30%;
    }
    .second-btn {
        margin-left: 39%;
        margin-top: 9%;
    }
    .third-btn {
        margin-left: 28%;
        margin-top: 6%;
    }
    .fourth-btn {
        margin-left: 35%;
    }
    .fifth-btn {
        margin-left: 30%;
    }
    .sixth-btn {
        margin-left: 9em;
    }
    .seventh-btn {
        margin-left: 31%;
    }
    .eigth-btn {
        margin-left: 30%;
        margin-bottom: 25%;
    }
    #divButton {
        margin-left: 43%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles2.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&family=Dancing+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">   
<!-- use font-family: Amatic SC, cursive -->
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<!-- <img src="images/backgroundbinary.png" alt="" class="bg-img"> -->
<body>
    <img src="images/backgroundbinary.png" alt="" class="bg-img">
    <header class="header1">
        <!-- <img src="images/backgroundbinary.png" alt="" class="bg-img"> -->
        <!-- <h4 class="name">Peter Ayad</h4> -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md">
            <!-- <div class="nav_toggle" id="nav-toggle"> -->
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">PA</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navLinks" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navLinks">
                <!-- <ul class="nav_menu" id="nav-menu"> -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="../index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="pages/About.html" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="pages/Resume.html" class="nav-link">Resume</a></li>
                    <!-- <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Projects</a></li> -->
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="../pages/Contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

         
        </nav>
        <!-- <h1 class="mainHeader">Welcome to Peter's Portfolio</h1> -->
    </header>


    <section class="project section">

        <h2 class="main-heading">Projects</h2>

        <div class="flex">
        <div class="first-project project">
            <div class="project-card">
                <h4>Project 1</h4>
                <img src="images/FireShot001.png" alt="" class="first-img img">
                <span></span>
                <p class="paragraph-title">This is the first project/Personal Profile Page</p>
                <p class="first-paragraph paragraph">The first project...The personal profile page. In this project I personalized my profile page by adding graphics, customizing and styling text, as well as improving the overall look and feel of the website. Take a look!</p>
                <form action="https://payad.github.io/Techdegree-Project-1/">
                <button class="btn first-btn">Click to view project</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        
        <div class="second-project project">
            <div class="project-card">
                <h4>Project 2</h4>
                <img src="images/FireShot009.png" alt="" class="second-img img">
                <span></span>
                <p class="paragraph-title">This is the second project/Responsive Layout</p>
                <p class="second-paragraph paragraph">The second project...The Responsive layout page. In this project I created a mobile-first responsive layout, 
                that included positioning elements side-by-side in a display, using inline-block, width, height, top and bottom margin and padding styles, as well as addiing different media queries for device viewports to layout the website. Take a look!</p>
                <form action="https://payad.github.io/Techdegree-project-2/">
                <button class="btn second-btn">Click to view project</button>
                </form>      
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex">
        <div class="third-project project">
            <div class="project-card">
                <h4 class="third-h4">Project 3</h4>
                <img src="images/FireShot003.png" alt="" class="third-img img">
                <span></span>
                <p class="paragraph-title">This is the third project/Online Registration Form</p>
                <p class="third-paragraph paragraph">The third project...The Online Registration Form. In this project I created a mobile-first registration form by using HTML tables, HTML forms, CSS selectors, and flexbox layout styles. Take a look!</p>
                <form action="https://payad.github.io/Techdegree-project-3/">
                <button class="btn third-btn">Click to view project</button>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="fourth-project project">
            <div class="project-card">
                <h4 class="fourth-h4">Project 4</h4>
                <img src="images/FireShot004.png" alt="" class="fourth-img img">
                <span></span>
                <p class="paragraph-title">This is the fourth project/Web Style Guide</p>
                <p class="fourth-paragraph paragraph">The fourth project...The Web Style Guide. In this project I created a web style guide acting as my own custom bootstrap that speeds up the process of styling, layout, and development using Sass . Take a look!</p>
                <form action="https://payad.github.io/Techdegree-project-4/">
                <button class="btn fourth-btn">Click to view project</button>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex">
        <div class="fifth-project project">
            <div class="project-card">
                <h4 class="fifth-h4">Project 5</h4>
                <img src="images/FireShot005.png" alt="" class="fifth-img img">
                <span></span>
                <p class="paragraph-title">This is the fifth project/Interactive Photo Gallery</p>
                <p class="fifth-paragraph paragraph">The fifth project...The Interactive Photo Gallery. In this project I created a interactive photo gallery using HTML, CSS, and Javascript (BuegetteBox pluggin) that allows you to search for a specific image by filtering keywords. Take a look!</p>
                <form action="https://payad.github.io/Techdegree-project-5/">
                <button class="btn fifth-btn">Click to view project</button>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sixth-project project">
            <div class="project-card">
                <h4 class="sixth-h4">Project 6</h4>
                <img src="images/FireShot006.png" alt="" class="sixth-img img">
                <span></span>
                <p class="paragraph-title">This is the sixth project/Game Show App</p>
                <p class="sixth-paragraph paragraph">The sixth project...The Game Show App. In this project I created a browser version of a word guessing game show app, that utilizes the uses of Javascript to generate random phrases for the user to guess by entering letters into the program. Take a look!</p>
                <form action="https://payad.github.io/Techdegree-project-6/">
                <button class="btn sixth-btn">Click to view project</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex">
        <div class="seventh-project project">
            <div class="project-card">
                <h4 class="seventh-h4">Project 7</h4>
                <img src="images/FireShot007.png" alt="" class="seventh-img img">
                <span></span>
                <p class="paragraph-title">This is the seventh project/WebApp DashBoard</p>
                <p class="seventh-paragraph paragraph">The seventh project...The WebApp DashBoard. In this project I created a dashboard application using advanced web technologies including SVG graphics, tables, charts and other interface components. Take a look!</p>
                <form action="https://payad.github.io/Techdegree-project-7/">
                <button class="btn seventh-btn">Click to view project</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="eigth-project project">
            <div class="project-card">
                <h4 class="eigth-h4">Project 8</h4>
                <img src="images/FireShot008.png" alt="" class="eigth-img img">
                <span></span>
                <p class="paragraph-title">This is the eighth project/Employee Directory</p>
                <p class="eigth-paragraph paragraph">the eighth project...The Employee Directory. In this project I created an employee directory using JS and AJAX to communicate with a web server, and the fetch API to retrieve random user images, and data to display employees. Take a look!</p>
                <form action="https://payad.github.io/Techdegree-project-8/">
                <button class="btn eigth-btn">Click to view project</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- <button class="bTop"></button> -->
        </div>

        <div class="divButton">
            <button class="bTop" onclick="topFunction()" id="bTop">Back To Top</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- <div class="ninth-project project">
            <div class="project-card">
                <h4>Project 9</h4>
                <img src="images/FireShot Capture 008 - Awesome Startup Employee Directory - payad.github.io.png" alt="" class="first-img">
                <span></span>
                <p>This is the nineth project/todo list</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fourth-project project">
            <div class="project-card">
                <h4>Project 10</h4>
                <img src="images/FireShot Capture 008 - Awesome Startup Employee Directory - payad.github.io.png" alt="" class="first-img">
                <span></span>
                <p>This is the tenth project/ecommerce</p>
            </div>
        </div> -->
    </section>
    <script src="app2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

To get a better example, at payad.github.io under the projects tab/ or when you click on "check out my work" button it takes you to the projects page where on 320px and 414px, the imgs are not centered and will not respond. Basically every time I change the code to center the images it reverts back, also sometimes Resolution Test is responsive sometimes its not. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: try `img { max-width: 100% }`

Comment: Hey @Kunal Tanwar, I used img {max-width: 100%}, but unfortunately it did not fix the issue, I have more pictures showing my chrome dev tools and the resolution test both 320px and 414px, (right img) and it is not changing or responding, is there something in my code that is preventing me from moving the imgs, I even tried to set the parent container to "positon: relative, and the child element with the img set to "position: absolute", and that didnt work either, please is there anything else i can do or change?